# Can a template class have pure virtual functions and virtual operators?

Tags: c++, templates, operators, pure-virtual

My professor was very adamant about how interface classes cannot be templated. Specifically, classes with pure virtual functions cannot have template parameters. Even further, he said that you cannot make virtual operators.

This was the example he was showing us at the time.

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
public:
  virtual void fill(T t) = 0;
  virtual T& operator[](size_t i) const = 0;
  // ... 
};
```

There's nothing wrong with this code right? Has there ever been a point in C++ history where this wouldn't compile? I used this exact form of code in an assignment and it works perfectly.

Comment: As far I know, the problem is that a virtual function can't be a template one. But nothing forbid a non-template virtual function in a template class (as in your example).

Comment: @max66 Thanks for the response. The prof was recommending having the virtual functions return an int or void and type casting the value at the call site. Yikes. He was surprised my code worked because it never worked for him in the past

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a template class have pure virtual functions and virtual operators?

Yes.

> There's nothing wrong with this code right?

Right.

> Has there ever been a point in C++ history where this wouldn't compile?

Possibly. I wouldn't be able to certainly say that it would compile with the original Cfront transpiler.

However, it is well-formed in any standard C++ version.

Comment: Cfront didn’t support templates at all. Templates and exceptions were described as future extensions in the Annotated Reference Manual. Their details were worked out and standardized in C++98. So this code would not have compiled with Cfront.